# Accessing instance variables using index

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a class which keeps track of errors encountered during a search operation

```
class SearchError(object): 
    def __init__(self,severity=0,message=''): 
        self.severity = severity
        self.message = message
```

My idea is to make the instance variables indexable.

So if I have

```
a=SearchError(1,"Fatal Error")
```

I get

```
>>> a[0]
1
>>> a[1]
'Fatal Error'
>>> a.severity
1
>>> a.message
'Fatal Error'
```

To do this I add a `__getitem__` method to the class. The class now becomes

```
class SearchError(object): 
    def __init__(self,severity=0,message=''): 
        self.severity = severity
        self.message = message

    def __getitem__(self,val): 
        if isinstance(val,slice): 
            return [self.__getitem__(i) for i in xrange(val.start,val.stop,val.step)]
        elif val==0: 
            return self.severity
        elif val==1: 
            return self.message
        else: 
            raise IndexError
```

This does what I want but fails in cases such as

```
>>> a[:2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 23, in __getitem__
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Or even

```
>>> a[-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 29, in __getitem__
IndexError
```

I understand my implementation of `__getitem__` is limited. What I need to know is -

1. Is this the way to make instance variables indexable (Without using a list as variable container)?
2. How do I make the object behave 'sanely' as far as indexing goes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mucked around the code and found the following solution.

It uses lists but to only store the names of the variables - Not the actual values. Additionally it also provides the method `add` to add a new variable with a given name and value. The new variable will also be indexable. (The add function is not needed by my class, but is nice to have around)

Thanks to @mgilson for nudging me in this direction

```
class SearchError(object): 
    def __init__(self,severity=0,message=''): 
        self.severity = severity
        self.message = message
        self._length = 2
        self._vars_list = ['severity','message',]

    def __getitem__(self,val): 
        if isinstance(val,slice): 
            steps = val.indices(self._length)
            return [self.__getitem__(i) for i in xrange(*steps)]
        elif val < 0: 
            i = self._length + val
            if i < 0: 
                raise IndexError,"Index Out of range for SearchError object"
            else: 
                return self.__getitem__(i)    
        else: 
            try: 
                return getattr(self,self._vars_list[val])
            except IndexError: 
                raise IndexError,"Index Out of range for SearchError object"

    def add(self,var_name,value): 
        self._vars_list.append(var_name)
        self._length += 1
        setattr(self,var_name,value)
```

The results

```
>>> a=SearchError(1,"Fatal Error")
>>> a[-1]
'Fatal Error'
>>> a[-2]
1
>>> a[-3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in __getitem__
IndexError: Index Out of range for SearchError object
>>> a[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 21, in __getitem__
IndexError: Index Out of range for SearchError object
>>> a[1]
'Fatal Error'
>>> a[0]
1
>>> a[:]
[1, 'Fatal Error']
>>> a.add('new_severity',8)
>>> a[:]
[1, 'Fatal Error', 8]
>>> a[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 21, in __getitem__
IndexError: Index Out of range for SearchError object
>>> a[2]
8
>>> a.new_severity
8
>>> a[:3]
[1, 'Fatal Error', 8]
>>> a[:4]
[1, 'Fatal Error', 8]
>>> a[:2]
[1, 'Fatal Error']
```

As far as I can see, you need lists (to either store the actual variables or their names). If someone has a better alternative please do post

Answer (score 1):

This does everything:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> _SearchError = namedtuple("SearchError", "severity message")
>>> def SearchError(severity=0, message=''):
        return _SearchError(severity, message)
```

Comment: Note that here your objects are immutable as a consequence of them being a tuple.  That may be fine for OP's application, but it might not so I think it is worth mentioning.

Comment: What if the class SearchError also has some methods?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `slice` objects default to having `None` values as attributes.  So, `a[:2]` passes in `slice(None,2,None)`.  When you break this apart and try to pass it to `xrange`, you'll get a `TypeError`:

```
>>> xrange(None,2,None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Try `a[0:2:1]` and your code will work.  Ultimately, you could do something like:

```
val.start = 0 if val.start is None else val.start
val.stop = 2 if val.stop is None else val.stop
val.stop = 2-val.stop if val.stop < 0 else val.stop
val.step = 1 if val.step is None else val.step
```

to unravel your slices into useable indices (In the general case, it'd be better to use `len(self)` instead of `2`, but I don't know if your object has defined `__len__`.

Or, even better:

```
start,stop,step = val.indices(len(self))
```

---

Similarly, in the case where you do `a[-1]`, you're not passing in a slice, a 0 or a 1, so you hit the `else` clause where you to raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the slice part. I got why a[-1] raises an indexerror but was just curious how can I make my objects behave like other indexable objects (lists,tuples). I also read somewhere that `slice` has a method (probably `indices()` or something) which chops off non-relevant indices and produces sane defaults. But then I would need to define the number of variables (length of the indexable)

Comment: @RedBaron -- Thanks for the `.indices` method.  I hadn't read about that one (although I was always certain that something like that *must exist*).  I'm glad to know what it is now -- That's a gem.

Answer (score 1):

`xrange` requires all its arguments to be integers, but `slice` objects have `None` for unspecified attributes.

The best way to implement what you're after is to use [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple
class SearchError(namedtuple('SearchError', 'severity message')):
    def __new__(cls, severity=0, message=''):
        return super(SearchError, cls).__new__(cls, severity, message)
```